# Problems running Pentaho Data Integration Error: Main class not found or loaded

Tags: integration, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, ubuntu-22.04, spoon

I have a problem, I am trying to run Pentaho Data Integration 9.4 in an Ubuntu 22.04 environment and it installed everything apparently correct, the Virtual Machine 8, and the dependencies that Pentaho needs but it turns out that when I run sh spoon.sh in the terminal it open the Pentaho because I get this error
spoon.sh: 74: cd: can't cd to /media/dayk/0DE412440DE41244/WORK/FREELANCER/Pentaho/PENTAHO
Error: Main class 9.4.Pentaho not found or loaded
This address is where I have the Pentaho /media/dayk/0DE412440DE41244/WORK/FREELANCER/Pentaho/PENTHO.
But no matter how many things I have checked, I cannot identify the problem.
Someone help me.
Thanks in advance,
Greetings
day

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veBmw.png)

Try checking the environment variables in JAVA HOME, run Pentaho that same installation and in Windows...

Comment: First, confirm that JAVA is installed and JAVA HOME is set properly then try to store the pdi file in the home directory of linux and try again For example /home/username/pdi-ce-9.4/

Comment: It seems like spoon is unable to process the blank space in your path to the installation. Try renaming the folders with a blank space in the name to something with a "-" or a "_" instead of the blank space.